# how to verify the content of the pop message in ruby capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I want to verify the content of the pop up message "Only Whole numbers" after submitting a form. Below is the code to submit the form:

```
fill_in 'allocationRegContrib[12].newFundValue', :with => workbook.cell(2,3)
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="allocationChangeDetails"]').click
sleep 5
expect(page).to have_content("Only Whole numbers")
```

Line 4 is the place where I want to check the content in the pop up . I get the error "unexpected alert open"

Then i tried in another way by adding the line 4 in the place where I accept the pop up. Below is the code:

```
Then (/^I accept popup for fractional part$/) do
expect(page).to have_content("Only Whole numbers")
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept 
end
```

here too i get the same error. Please Advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in a cross driver manner with capybara you need to change your steps slightly since the step that triggers the alert needs to know it's coming

```
When (/^I do something and accept popup for fractional part$/) do
  accept_alert "Only Whole numbers" do
    # the do something code that triggers the alert box
  end
end
```

If you're using the accept popup in more than one place you could do something along the lines of

```
When (/^(.+) and accept popup for fractional part$/) do |step_name|
  accept_alert "Only Whole numbers" do
    step(step_name)
  end
end
```

or more generally

```
When (/^(.+) and accept "([^"]+)"$/) do |step_name, alert_text|
  accept_alert alert_text do
    step(step_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried the way u mentioned but i get the error:     ** Unable to find modal dialog with Only Whole numbers (Capybara::ModalNotFound)**

Comment: Ok -- are you sure the text matches exactly to whats in the alert box?

Comment: try it without the "Only Whole numbers" and see if it works -- if it does it means the text isn't correct

Comment: You were right. The letter "W" was not in bigger case. That is where I missed. I now want to use your 3rd way since I need to use accept pop up more than once.

Comment: Great - glad it helped -- don't forget to accept the answer so others not the issue is resolved